# Minimum number of attendees in a party

Tags: graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

At a party, you realise that everyone, except you, has shaken
hands with exactly three other people; you have shaken hands
with only one other person. Determine the minimum number of
attendees at this party.

So i know that if n is the minimum number of attendees, it must be an even number. And the total number of handshakes has to be (3n-2)/2. No leads after this.

This came up while solving an old question paper for an entrance exam.I dont know graph theory so I am trying to attempt this using pigeon hole principle or some general logic that doesnt involve very advanced knowledge of graph theory. Can anyone give a hint or help solve this?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  $4$ is impossible, right?  Can you do it with $6$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I think I see the intent of your hint, but maybe $n-2$ is more suggestive than $n-1$.

Comment: Hint: If you can find a way for $n-2$ people to shake hands with exactly three other people, then find a way to insert yourself and one other person to satisfy the conditions of the problem.  $\quad$  (Ah yes, the $n-2$ construction is much more natural and quicker.)

Comment: Yeah, just noticed it cant be done with 4 people and an easy construction shows that it can be done with 6 vertices. Thanks!

Still thinking about the n-2 hint though.